# Responsive Mobile Website Design

Tags: css, mobile

I have created a responsive website which has a mobile.css with multiple sizes to suit most common devices. What is the best practice from your experience to ensure that each size I have specified in my mobile.css will format the page correctly on all devices.

What I am wanting to achieve is a stretching of elements to fit the page when within the specified min/max limits specified in mobile.css. Are percentages the best practice to achieve this?

Let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is test it on each device. You don't need to have every device that there is, you only need a device with a fixed screen size. Also try to get devices with different browsers, opera, chrome, IEmobile etc. Thats the safest.

There are websites out there that can emulate device sizes and display your website in those scales, But they do not emulate the mobile browsers. See if you can get a couple devices.(Ask friends and family or co workers.) And test it on each size you can.

Best of luck

Comment: "Dimensions Legacy" for chrome is an awesome plugin to test :)

Comment: It is, i was just playing with it now. Very great!

Comment: Haven't heard of "Dimensions Legacy" will give it a look :) Absolutely every device needs to be considered.

Answer (score 0):

@Media Queries are best practice in my experience refer to [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) and there are some [really nice examples](http://mediaqueri.es/)

When testing FireFox has a default User Agent Plugin that can act as different Browsers, You can also get the Web developer Extension which has a resize menu to show you the responsive versions of your sites. Google Chrome has similar plugins.

Comment: Ive been using @Media Queries make it easier to style the sit at different widths more precisely. Im using quiet a few about 10 now for the various potential sizes for mobile devices, is this to many?

Comment: The number of media queries are your call but 10 sounds like you are making too much work for yourself. Most are based on size ranges, have a look at twitter bootstrap for a good example

Comment: Im using that many due to the resize on the PC to make it more seamless, you are right a lot more work and a large css file. I have had a look at Twitter Boostrap, will go through some online tuts.